# Which is the best method to use of my bundle images in project if i have large amount of images for project

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

My iOS project is compatible with iPhone and iPad both and I have many image resources. some of them are large in size.
It will effect my app performance some times.

So Which option i should use for accessing resources for my ViewController.

Comment: Place your 1x, 2x and 3x in Assets.xcassets. And Whenever you want use them, load them programmatically. Do not assign directly in storyboard controllers. And for binding UI Controles use "weak" attribute.

Comment: @Wolverine Means i have to take IBOutlet for every imageview in storyboard and access it programetically.

Comment: Yes. Some times when you directly assign images in storyboard, it is not releasing that memory related to those controls.

Comment: @Wolverine Same problem I am facing when new ViewController Push memory will continuously increasing... Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Also follow these steps for handling memory issues. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-ios-memory/

Comment: Show your code. How are you differentiating phone and pad images?